# Allocation error by deleting symbol layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

In my plugin I have a loop where a Symbol is created in first run through. 
During next steps the symbollayerlist should be filled.

In creating with standard constructor always a symbollayer is added. So I tried to delete the symbollayer in first time. But this causes a memory allocation error.

Then I tried to give the constructor an empty layerlist created by myself, so should I can delete the layers by myself, but also the constructor addes automatically an layer and I get the error by deleting it.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
QgsSymbolV2 * p_Symbol(0); 
bool oFirst=true; 

... 

if (oFirst) 
{ 
        QgsSymbolLayerV2List * sLyrs= new QgsSymbolLayerV2List();
        qDebug()<<QString::number(sLyrs->count());
        QgsFillSymbolV2* p_FSymbol = new QgsFillSymbolV2(*sLyrs);
        qDebug()<<QString::number(p_FSymbol->symbolLayerCount());
        p_Symbol = dynamic_cast <QgsSymbolV2 *>(p_FSymbol); 
        qDebug()<<QString::number((int)p_Symbol,16); 
        qDebug()<<QString::number(p_Symbol->symbolLayerCount()); 
        if (p_Symbol->symbolLayerCount()==1) 
                p_Symbol->deleteSymbolLayer(0); 
        oFirst=false; 
} 
...
```

Output:

```
"0"
"1"
"1847bca0" 
"1" 
First-chance exception at 0x77e4e43e in qgis-bin.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4d46be13. 
Unhandled exception at 0x77e4e43e in qgis-bin.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4d46be13.
```

What could be the reason?
I use **QGIS 2.18.11** and **Visual Studio 2010** on Win7.
In prior Version QGIS 2.14.3 and Visual Studio 2008 this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: This is more of a software development question than a GIS one, especially in light of the compiler depenency. Asking this in [so] proper seems more likely to generate an answer.